# Extjs: drag n drop tree node and its children to a grid

Tags: extjs, drag-and-drop, extjs4.2, treepanel

How can I drag and drop a node(parent) and all its children without selecting them, when the parent node is selected and dragged in the tree?

[Sample code which I have tried](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/h0u)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `beforedrop` event, you need to add the child nodes to the `data.records` array.  Every record in that array will be included in the drag & drop process.  Likewise, if you did not want to include a node that was dragged and dropped, you would remove that record from `data.records` while in the `beforedrop` event.

Please take a look at [my sample code](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/m8k) to see an approach for how to add the child nodes.

The relevant piece is:

```
var childNodes = Ext.Array.from(record.childNodes) || []; // ensure it's an array

for (var i=0; i < childNodes.length; i++) {
    data.records.push(childNodes[i]);
}
```